# Ровно или равно?

Tags: выбор-слова

Оба слова переводятся на польский и английский языки как "równy" и "equal", соответственно.

Есть ли между ними какая-то разница?

Comment: Is there a sample sentence where you are not sure which one to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это довольно разные слова, причем их тут не два, а три.

**рáвно** (adverb): "equally", "in equal measure"

e.g. *равно влияет на них* "affects them equally"

**равнó** (predicate): "equals", "is equal to", "is tantamount to"

e.g. *равно нулю* "is equal to zero"

**рóвно** (adverb): "exactly", "straight", "in a level way", "smoothly", "uniformly"

e.g. *ровно в два* "at two [o'clock] sharp", *стоять ровно* "to stand straight", *ровно сто* "exactly a hundred", *дорога тянулась ровно* "the road stretched smoothly"

Comment: that's a textbook example of CS and Russian cognates with different meanings

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос, собственно, сводится к следующим:

Почему мы землю р<kbd>о</kbd>вняли, а получили р<kbd>а</kbd>внину?

```
   równina                            Polish
   равнина                            Russian
```

Почему два человека р<kbd>а</kbd>вного возраста р<kbd>о</kbd>весники?

```
   rówieśnik                          Polish
   ровесник                           Russian
```

Рассмотрим такую диаграмму:

```
       Polish             English      Russian


                          flatten  --> ровнять      
  one root ┐_ równać __ /               |___________ one root = ро/ав  
  one word ┘            \               |
                          equal    --> равнять
```

В английском две лексемы. В русском и польском одна, но в русском с изменяемой гласной в корне. В русском безударные гласные произносятся в зависимости от погоды, времени суток, места проживания и количества выпитых спиртных напитков )) Видимо, эта вариативность и позволила не брать новую лексему, а закрепить в письменном языке два различных значения, сохранив основу в корневой морфеме. На слух, если гласные без ударения, нельзя с уверенностью сказать, какое слово сказано.

Comment: На самом деле, как отметил @Quassnoi, варианты на ра- — церковнославянские, а на ро- — исконно русские, и эта двойственность была еще до развития аканья. Которое, конечно, тут всё добавочно перемешало.

Comment: @NikolayErshov , звучит вполне правдоподобно.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the value. If you would like to say:

> "У меня на это ушло рОвно две недели", use "ровно".

In another case:

> "Два минус один рАвно один"

or

> "Мне все рАвно, когда это произойдет",

you should use 'A'